# Setting environment variable permanently from java

Tags: java

Using Java, 
How can I add environment variable permanently to the existing env variables.

so that when I do a restart operation for windows or Linux, this environment variable is still there.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Or are you looking for an OS agnostic solution?

Comment: Are you trying to write some system management tool using Java, or are you trying to modify configuration for your own app? Because if it is the latter, I would say move you configuration to someplace else.

Comment: following up on what @DilumRanatunga said, the Preferences API is a great way to save per-user config in a system agnostic way.

Comment: ... but the preferences API make no guarantees about anything. Very unfortunate.

Comment: I'm using Windows
but I need this functionality for both platforms

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051775/using-java-to-do-a-windows-command-line-command).

In Windows you can [set a Path Variable from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-xp) so it should do the trick.

I realize this is only applicable to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Not in any cross platform sort of way.  In Linux, these are typically controlled via shell init scripts.  You would have to edit one of those (which one depends on the user, system, and shell type).  In Windows, this is controlled via system configuration (i'd imagine there are some windows specific APIs to modify those).

Answer (score 0):

coppy the path of jdk upto C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin from program and past in user variables and put ;.; at the end and give name  .
and in system variables click on new and enter the name and past the path....and save ...

Answer (score 0):

go to command prompt
..
to check current paths >echo %path%
to set path >set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin" enter ok now check and run java program

Answer (score -2):

Environment variables are platform specific. Windows stores them in Registry.

*In the registry the User environment variables are stored at
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
and the System environment variables are stored at
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
(from http://demins.blogspot.co.il/2007/10/where-does-windows-xp-store-evrironment.html)*

There are a lot of ways to access windows registry from java. You can for example execute command line using utility named `reg` that has a reach command line. You can also use one of interoparability APIs like JaWin, Jinterop, Jintegra. You can also refer to my solution explained [here](http://alexradzin.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/access-windows-registry-with-pure-java.html).

On linux you can use command line like `export MYVAR=myvalue`. I mean execute this command line from java using `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder`. The problem is that this variable will not become really persistent. It will be visiable for all users until the computers is restarted. To make it really persistent you have to modify user login script (e.g. `bashrc` file for most linux systems if users's default shell is bash).

Comment: for the linux solution, running `export` from a sub-process will not influence anything except subsequent processes run in that same sub-process (it won't influence anything else done by the current user, and certainly not any other users).  in fact, that command won't even run as is because you need a shell to execute it.

Comment: @jtahlborn, sorry that I forgot to mention to run command as `/bin/sh export ...` or something like this. I believe that this detail can be discovered by OP himself.

Comment: that addresses one minor part of what i said, but none of the major points.