# Permanently Setting PATH System Environment Variable

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I need to **permanently** modify the system's `PATH` environment variable. For this I'm planning to check if the folder I'm about to add already exists and only if it doesn't, it gets added.

```
String pathToAdd = "C:\\Example\\bin";
String pathContents = getPathSystemEnvironmentValue();
if(!pathContents.contains(pathToAdd))
{
    pathContents += ";" + pathToAdd;
}

setPathSystemEnvironmentValue(pathContents);
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to retrieve and set the `PATH` environment variable conveniently. I've seen that it can be done by using the [setx](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc755104.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command but it would not use any Java code and it's obviously not platform-independent. I also want to avoid [calling external batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051775/using-java-to-do-a-windows-command-line-command). I know that Java wasn't meant to do native tasks like this but is there a decent solution though? Possibly compatible with `Linux` as well.

Comment: Why would you want to do this (especially permanently)?

Comment: @tjalling
I'm making a software utility that helps installing other software on the system which needs environment variables to be set

Comment: I was way too hasty casting my duplicate flag. Please decline the flag!

Comment: Permanently changing environment variables is not possible in a platform independent way. Windows stores those in the registry, Linux usually uses `/etc/profile` or similar. *BSDs have `login.conf`. And of course there's systemd ...

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Why not install that software using the target OS' normal installation locations? (purely in response to PATH, not talking about custom environment variables)

Comment: @Rainbolt The answers there change the environment for the current process (and children, [Java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)). The tricky bit is the *permanent*.